# Return a property of current page list item in carousel page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, carousel

I'm creating a Lyrics app using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 19. All the songs details are written inside a `songs.json` file.

JSON File looks like:

```
{
   "song" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "title" : "ABC", 
        "lyrics" : "ABCDE", 
        "album" : "XYZ" 
      },
      {
        ........
      }, 
      ........
      ........
      } 
   ] 
}
```

Each of these song details are inserted into a new collection list and are binded into a `Carousel Page` using `ItemTemplate`.

How we can return `id` property value of currently displayed item inside the `Carousel Page`.

I heard about `OnCurrentPageChanged()` but don't know how to achieve using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a `CarosuelView`.  `CarosuelPage` is deprecated

```
var item = (MyModel)myCarousel.CurrentItem;
var id = item.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed to ```CarouselView.```